# what is the difference between werthers soft and chewy candies

Tags: caramel

What is the difference between Werthers soft caramels and chewy caramels? I have also seen "soft and chewy". Are those different than those other two?

Answer (score 2):

[The company website](https://www.werthers-original.us/en/products/soft-caramels) has a clear explanation of its products, which include hard caramels, soft caramels, and chewy caramels.  I think "hard" is self-explanatory.  Soft appear to be the texture of filled chocolates or caramels...easy to bite through.  "Chewy" are stickier and stretchier.  I don't see a "soft and chewy" product on their website, but it is possible I've missed it.